# Can connect to one Azure DB but not another

Tags: azure

Two years ago I created a SQL Server .database.windows.net and that works fine, I can connect through the azure portal and my local SSMS.

Today I created a new SQL Server .database.windows.net
But I can not connect through SSMS or even the Azure Portal

The azure portal gives the error

> A connection to the server 'youtube-mb.database.windows.net' could not be established. This might indicate an issue with your local firewall configuration or your network proxy settings.

I know it complains about a firewall but I can't believe that is the issue is due to my local firewall since one server works and the other does not.  And other on premise SQL Servers connect.

I also check

- the password is correct (by resetting it)
- the firewall configurations in azure are the same

  - Minimum TLS > 1.0
  - Connection Policy - Default
  - Allow Azure services and resources access to this server
  - My IP whitelisted

Not sure what else to look at, especially if Quick Query is not working in the portal itself.

Answer (score 0):

The firewall rule is set at the server level, so you have to add an firewall rule exception for each Azure SQL Server instance you create to access it from your PC.

Comment: So I understand are you saying my PC firewall is set for each instance... I though it was just a pass through on port 1433.  Or are you referring the the azure firewall settings, which I did compare between the two and they look the same